# Telnet device automation

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib, netmiko, napalm

I try to connect to devices with python using telnet protocole to do some automation (for example somes old Cisco routers),
For that i am using Napalm library (which based on Napalm library which based on telnetlib library)

The problem is that when i use directly telnetlib library it's works fine, but when i use Napalm or
Netmiko it gives this error: get Telnet login failed.

Doeas anyone had this situation before?

PS: i tried some solution find in internet but nothing works.

Thank you in advance.

This code works (telnetlib library):

```
import telnetlib
import time
from pprint import pprint


def to_bytes(line):
    return f"{line}\n".encode("utf-8")


def send_show_command(ip, username, password, enable, commands):
    with telnetlib.Telnet(ip) as telnet:
        telnet.read_until(b"Username")
        telnet.write(to_bytes(username))
        telnet.read_until(b"Password")
        telnet.write(to_bytes(password))
        index, m, output = telnet.expect([b">", b"#"])
        if index == 0:
            telnet.write(b"enable\n")
            telnet.read_until(b"Password")
            telnet.write(to_bytes(enable))
            telnet.read_until(b"#", timeout=5)
        telnet.write(b"terminal length 0\n")
        telnet.read_until(b"#", timeout=5)
        time.sleep(3)
        telnet.read_very_eager()

        result = {}
        for command in commands:
            telnet.write(to_bytes(command))
            output = telnet.read_until(b"#", timeout=5).decode("utf-8")
            result[command] = output.replace("\r\n", "\n")
        return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    devices = ["1.1.1.1"]
    commands = ["sh ip int br"]
    for ip in devices:
        result = send_show_command(ip, "username", "password", "", commands)
        pprint(result, width=120)
```

This code return login error (napalm library):

```
from napalm import get_network_driver
from pprint import pprint
  
driver = get_network_driver('ios')
conn_method = {'port': 23, 'transport': 'telnet', 'global_delay_factor': 2, 'secret': ''}
host = '1.1.1.1'
user = 'username'
passwd = 'password'
  

with driver(hostname=host, username=user, password=passwd, optional_args=conn_method ) as device:
    print('Getting facts')
    pprint(device.get_facts())
```

This code return login error (netmiko library):

```
import os
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

switch = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios_telnet',
    'ip': '1.1.1.1',
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "timeout": 15

}

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**switch)
print(net_connect)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Libraries such as these often provide the means to see the actual bytes being sent and received with appropriate configuration.  You might want to search the documentation for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already mentioned `NAPALM` uses `telnetlib` for telnet connections. But it uses it with the help of `netmiko`.

Regarding your question, the issue could be raised due to some factors:

1. Connection timeout
2. Authentication timeout

Try to add `conn_timeout: 30` and `auth_timeout: 30` in `conn_method` variable *(30 seconds is an example)* to give time for your application to connect and authenticate to the network device.

Also a recommendation to set `fast_cli` to `False` (default value is `True`). `fast_cli` simply multiplies the **delay factor** by 0.1. So if you have a delay factor of 1 (100 seconds), it means the application has 10 seconds only to screen scrape what is happening on the remote network device which is not always enough in some cases. **This behavior is only in the case of using `CiscoBaseConnection`.**

> For `BaseConnection`, `fast_cli` default value is `False`.

Here is a complete working demo of your case

```py
from pprint import pprint

from napalm import get_network_driver

driver = get_network_driver("ios")

creds = {
    "hostname": "192.168.1.150",
    "username": "cisco",
    "password": "cisco",
}

optionals = {
    "transport": "telnet",  # no need for port 23. It implicilty knows what port to set
    "secret": "", 
    "conn_timeout": 30,
    "auth_timeout": 30,
    "fast_cli": False,  # no need for global_delay_factor now in case of get_facts() only
}


with driver(**creds, optional_args=optionals) as device:
    print("Port:", device.device.port)  # prints 23
    print("Parsing facts...")
    facts = device.get_facts()
pprint(facts)
```

Comment: Thank you @Tes3awy for your help